# Do tiles look darker when hanging on a wall than they'll appear when layed horizontally on the floor?

Tags: flooring, tile, ceramic-tile, stone, marble

The salesman in the showroom told us that the tiles we see hanging on the wall will be 20% lighter when are layed down horizontaly on the floor, so we should take into account when choosing our prefered color.

Is this true or it's only a sales people myth? (I tried to google to find anybody mention this interesting fact but couldn't really find any source for that)
[image]

**Update**: 2 years later after the house was built I can share that the tiles actually looks **darker** when layed down on the floor that it looked on the store.

Turns out that what @isherwood said is correct and it's all about lightning. At the store there was direct light on the tiles so they look brighter, on the house on places where the tiles don't have direct light on them they look darker.

Comment: How does the sunlight come into the room? Think about the lights in the room - how does the light hit the wall and floor? angle?

Comment: Thank you for your update based on your actual experience. Feedback like this is valuable to all readers. Indeed, not only the lighting itself, but also the colour of the walls and ceiling will have an effect on the perceived colour of the tiles, and vice versa, the flooring has an effect on the perceived colour of the walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither strictly true *nor* a myth. It's an oversimplified (and arbitrarily quantified) suggestion that has some merit. Check color *in your room* with the lighting it'll actually have. It's more likely that color will vary due to light source color and reflected color from other elements of the room's design than installation orientation, though.